# R - Get row numbers where two matrices have equal rows

Tags: r, matrix, find, rows, equals

I have to matrices and I want to no which rows are identical.

Lets say I have a matrix A which looks like this:
`A = matrix(1:12, 4, 3, byrow=T)`

> `[,1] [,2] [,3]`
>
> `[1,]    1    2    3`
>
> `[2,]    4    5    6`
>
> `[3,]    7    8    9`
>
> `[4,]   10   11   12`

a shorter matrix B: `B <-matrix(c(0,2,2,7,8,9,4,5,6),3,3,byrow=T)`

> `[,1] [,2] [,3]`
>
> `[1,]  0  2  2`
>
> `[2,]  7  8  9`
>
> `[3,]  4  5  6`

What I want is the row numbers of A when the rows are also present in B.
In this example I would like to get: `2` and `3`.

I tried to solve it with setkey but then I get only the rows but not the number of the row since the matrices are first sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you could use `match_df` from `plyr`:

```
match_df(data.frame(A),data.frame(B))
Matching on: X1, X2, X3
  X1 X2 X3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

And to extract the numbers of the rows you could type `as.numeric(rownames(match_df(data.frame(A),data.frame(B))))`

Comment: Thank you!
In my real case I used something like this B<-which(C!=0, arr.ind=TRUE) to generate my matrix B. Therefore I had to reset my dimnames like this:
dimnames(B) = NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can `rbind` the matrices together and use `duplicated` to figure out which rows are duplicated:

```
> duplicated(rbind(A, B), fromLast = TRUE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> which(duplicated(rbind(A, B), fromLast = TRUE))
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: How about the case of `A <- rbind(A,A)`?

Comment: What if there are duplicates in one or on both of the matrices?

Comment: Thanks. As @RStudent pointed out, this approach failed for my real case since I have thousands of equal rows.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know to do it is to convert matrix to string by rows:

```
sA <- apply(A,1,paste,collapse=' ')
sB <- apply(B,1,paste,collapse=' ')

which(sA %in% sB)
# [1] 2 3
```